# How to add the key of a dictionary to dataframe of value is in range of a dictionary value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

A sample df is shown below:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'Price':[10,8,7,6,10,12,11,11,7,9], 'Group':['apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','berry','berry','berry','berry','berry']})
```

| Price | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | apple |
| 8 | apple |
| 7 | apple |
| 6 | apple |
| 10 | apple |
| 12 | berry |
| 11 | berry |
| 11 | berry |
| 7 | berry |
| 9 | berry |

Nested dictionaries with a range of values for each key:

```py
apple={'A':[9, 10], 'B':[6, 8], 'C':[3,5]}
berry={'A':[11, 12], 'B':[6, 9]}
```

Add the column `Cat` to the df, with the corresponding key within each `Group` if `Price` is within the range of values of each key. The output:

```
Price   Group    Cat
    10  apple    A
    8   apple    B
    7   apple    B
    6   apple    B
    10  apple    A
    12  berry    A
    11  berry    A
    11  berry    A
    7   berry    B
    9   berry    B
```

Could this be achieved using any built-in functions in python or any other ways using a function that takes in df and dicts?

Answer (score 0):

With `df` the DataFrame and

```
D = {
    "apple":{'A':[9, 10], 'B':[6, 8], 'C':[3,5]},
    "berry":{'A':[11, 12], 'B':[6, 9]}
}
```

Try:

```
df["cat"] = df[["Price", "Group"]].apply(lambda x: next(k for k,v in D[x[1]].items() if v[0] <= x[0] <= v[1] ), axis = 1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
Price   Group   cat
    10  apple   A
    8   apple   B
    7   apple   B
    6   apple   B
    10  apple   A
    12  berry   A
    11  berry   A
    11  berry   A
    7   berry   B
    9   berry   B
```

This does not check wether at least one appropiate interval exists, and might crash if **no interval** fit(because `next()` will be applied on an empty iterator)

Comment: It has to check if the value in the df fits within the intervals in dict, otherwise on what criteria does it add the value to the new column in df?

Comment: It does that (check the output). But it might crash if no interval fits the value

Comment: it is possible to have such case and it breaks, unfortunately.

Comment: What would be the expected behaviour then ?

Comment: So if there is no value that fits into C:[3,5] is should still work for the existing values in the df without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it preferable to avoid `apply` or iterations over rows, and preferable to handle columns, as intended by pandas. "Generally speaking". Because no dogma is never entirely true. For example, in your case, if you have more categories in your dictionaries (combination "fruit group"/"price categories") than you have rows, in your dataframe, then, iterating rows is not that bad.

But if you have, as most dataframes (that is the point of dataframes. Otherwise, they have not much advantage over simple list, dictionaries and such) lot of rows, you may prefer such a solution:

```py
for gr in D:
    for cat in D[gr]:
        df.loc[(df.Group==gr) & (df.Price>=D[gr][cat][0]) & (df.Price<=D[gr][cat][1]), 'Cat'] = cat
```

with the same D as in PlainRavioli's answer.

Note that it doesn't suffer any problem if a line doesn't fit in any category. It just leaves that 'Cat' field untouched (that is, if there were no such field before, to `NA`).

Timings are in favor of PlainRavioli's method with your examples. Because, well, I am also iterating, just over the dictionary D categories rather than over rows. And you have almost as many categories than you have of rows.

But on a dataframes of 1000 rows, for example, there is a factor 10 in favor of this method.